# Rails server error not clear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

Using OS X Sierra

I have a rails app with two parts: front-end and back-end.
On back-end I am using rails 4.
On the front-end I am using Angular.
Whenever I have to start the server locally (for development or test) I use 3 distinct console windows.

one to run `grunt watch`"

another to run `http-server ./build/ -p 8000 -c-1`

and the last to run `rails server`

My local backend repository is just a clone of what is running on production.(minus server configuration)

When I use the fronted connected to my remote server it works without problems. However, when I run the backend locally and try to log in, all I get is the following log, and no responses:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.7 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2017-01-02 16:19:21] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-01-02 16:19:21] INFO  ruby 2.3.3 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-darwin15]
[2017-01-02 16:19:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=10496 port=3000
```

The front end throws the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/auth_user? 
>   email=admin@railsapp.com&password=VVVVVVVV. Cross origin requests are
>   only supported for HTTP.

My Angular endpoint file

```
angular.module( 'common.config', [] )
.factory('endpoints', function() {
  var host = 'development';

  if (['live.companysite.com'].indexOf(window.location.host) > -1) {
host = 'production';
  } else if (['companysite.com'].indexOf(window.location.host) > -1) {
    host = 'development';
  } else {
    host = 'local';
  }

  var endpoints = {
    'production': {
      root: 'http://live.companysite.com/'
    },
    'development': {
      root: 'http://companysite.com/'
    },
    'local': {
      root: 'localhost:3000/'
    }
  };

  return endpoints[host];
});
```

**I know that it should be a CORS problem, but as it works perfectly with two remote servers (production and test) I believe that my local configuration might be the problem.**

Comment: 'localhost:3000auth_user?emai' I think you are missing an / before auth_user and after :3000, check the line where you define the api in your angular project, probably you need to add a slash /

Comment: @HugoFarji fixed that, but still getting the same error

Comment: @HugoFarji Turns out I had to put "http://" before my endpoint. Don't now how I missed that all this time. Thanks! 

Now i have:
   
'local': {
  root: "http:// localhost:3000/"
}

Could you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'localhost:3000auth_user?emai' I think you are missing an '/' before auth_user and after :3000, check the line where you define the api in your angular project, probably you need to add a slash .
Check changing this in your config:

```
'local': { root: "http:// localhost:3000/" }
```